# Jquery delay() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**NOTE**: I am horrible in framing question titles. Please excuse !

The following is my code where `magic` is a class-name of a `div`

```
$(".magic")             
   .text("You shouldn't have been here")
   .delay(4000)
   .ghosttyper({                  
      messages: ['3', '2', '1'],
      repeat: false,
      timePause: 900,
      callback: function(){
            console.log("timer stopped.");   
         }
});
```

For some reason after the text is displayed, time is not delayed until the next function is called.It just happens real quick. I am using the [ghost-typer](https://github.com/lokeshthegenius/ghost-typer) plugin for jQuery and I believe its got nothing to do with the time not delaying.

Comment: I don't think `delay` supports all jQuery functions (for instance being chained to `text()`

Comment: So what can i do now ? how to get it delayed ?

Comment: Agree with @Djave view and you can use `setTimeout`

Comment: Yes as @Satpal mentioned, setTimeout is exactly the right way to go. https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Comment: Using `delay()`, you need to put relevant code in `queue()`: `.delay(4000).queue(function(n){$(this).ghosttyper({...}); n();})`

Comment: @A.Wolff Isn't the `ghosttyper` a relevant queue member ?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti I don't know this plugin

Comment: @TilakMadichetti that depends on how it's coded. If it's not working with `delay()` it doesn't use a jQuery queue. You'll need to use `setTimeout()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Not tested but gives you the gist)

```
                $(".magic") 

                    .text("You shouldn't have been here")

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".magic").ghosttyper({

                            messages: ['3', '2', '1'],
                            repeat: false,
                            timePause: 900,
                            callback: function(){

                                console.log("timer stopped.");

                            }
                        })},
                        4000
                    }
```